# Sort and display items by count of occurrences

Tags: ruby

I find myself repeatedly wanting to count the number of occurrences of an item in an array and display the top items along with their actual count. I have written code like the following so many times I recognize it as a recurring, RSI-inducing pattern:

```
hits = Hash[ array.group_by{|o|o}.map{|o,a|[o,a.length]}.sort_by{|o,ct|[-ct,o]} ]

require 'pp'
pp hits
```

I could move this into a monkeypatch on Enumerable…

```
module Enumerable
  def counts(&blk)
    blk ||= ->(o){o}
    Hash[ group_by(&blk).map{|o,a| [o,a.length] }.sort_by{|o,ct| [-ct,o] } ]
  end
end

a = %w[a b a b c d e g j a e c d k o k i l p a e c f d e a d e f s d v c ]
pp a.counts
#=> {"a"=>5,
#=>  "d"=>5,
#=>  "e"=>5,
#=>  "c"=>4,
#=>  "b"=>2,
#=>  "f"=>2,
#=>  "k"=>2,
#=>  "g"=>1,
#=>  "i"=>1,
#=>  "j"=>1,
#=>  "l"=>1,
#=>  "o"=>1,
#=>  "p"=>1,
#=>  "s"=>1,
#=>  "v"=>1}
```

…but I wonder if there's a more elegant way to accomplish this (less typing would suffice) using core Ruby methods.

Comment: It looks good to me, though using Hash.new(0)+inject (or each_with_object) would be more efficient than `group_by`. Note that there are already quite a lot of questions answering "frequency of elements in an array" showing both group_by and inject solutions.

Comment: @tokland I'll happily close this answer for a duplicate (I didn't find one) or accept an answer showing this iff the result has the hash keys or paired array sorted by descending hits.

Comment: Phrogz, I've found your recent Ruby questions interesting (particularly the ones involving combinatorics), so am having a look at some of your older questions.  I'll probably post comments and solutions from time-to-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the code I have is about as terse as it's going to get. Moved into a non-monkeypatching method:

```
def count_items(enum,&blk)
  blk ||= ->(o){o}
  Hash[ enum.group_by(&blk).map{|o,a| [o,a.length] }.sort_by{|o,ct| [-ct,o] } ]
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :041 > Hash[*[1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5].inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse.flatten]

=> {5=>3, 1=>2, 4=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1}
```

**Listen if you are looking to rank the list based on no of occurrences, the following works well,**

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :045 > [1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5].group_by{|x| x}.sort_by{|k, v| -v.size}.map(&:first)

=> [5, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Note that under Ruby 1.8.7+ you can just use `Hash[ array_of_tuples ]` instead of `Hash[ *array_of_tuples.flatten ]`

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting in advance, which might be slow for high n:

```
a = %w[a b a b c d e g j a e c d k o k i l p a e c f d e a d e f s d v c ]
a.each_with_object( {} ) {|e, h| h[e] ||= 0; h[e] += 1 }.sort_by {|o, ct| [-ct, o] }
```

If you care about elegance, use #with_object / #each_with_object when suitable.